# Hibernate - Column of Embedded missing in Audit Table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers, hibernate-5.x

I am using hibernate version **5.3.18.Final** but I face an issue with the Embedded object with the Audit table

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [createDate] in table [audit.Address_AUD]
```

here is the full code

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "address_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Address_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Address_generator", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "address_sequence")
    private Long addressId;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Version
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long version;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="addresses")
    private List<AddressGroup> addressGroups;

    public Long getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }

    public void setAddressId(Long addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Embedded
    private TemporalEntity temporal;

    public TemporalEntity getTemporal() { return temporal; }

    public void setTemporal(TemporalEntity temporal) { this.temporal = temporal; }

    public List<AddressGroup> getAddressGroups() {
        return addressGroups;
    }

    public void setAddressGroups(List<AddressGroup> addressGroups) {
        this.addressGroups = addressGroups;
    }

}

@Embeddable
public class TemporalEntity {

    @Column(updatable = false)
    private DateTime createDate;

    @Column
    private DateTime lastModifiedDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by_id", updatable = false)
    private AdminUser createdBy;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by_id")
    private AdminUser lastModifiedBy;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean not null default false")
    private boolean deleted = false;

    public DateTime getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(DateTime createDate) {
        if (createDate == null) {
            //ignore attempts to clear this field
            return;
            //throw new IllegalStateException("Null create date not allowed");
        }
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public DateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(DateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        if (lastModifiedDate == null) {
            //ignore attempts to clear this field
            return;
            //throw new IllegalStateException("Null last modified date not allowed");
        }
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public AdminUser getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(AdminUser createdBy) {
        if (createdBy == null) {
            //ignore attempts to clear this field
            return;
            //throw new IllegalStateException("Null created by not allowed");
        }
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public AdminUser getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(AdminUser lastModifiedBy) {
        if (lastModifiedBy == null) {
            //ignore attempts to clear this field
            return;
            //throw new IllegalStateException("Null lastModifiedBy not allowed");
        }
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

}
```

the error log

```
18:58:48,265 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."bds-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#com.berwick.dal": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."bds-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#com.berwick.dal": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: com.berwick.dal] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:198) [wildfly-jpa-21.0.0.Final.jar:21.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128) [wildfly-jpa-21.0.0.Final.jar:21.0.0.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_221]
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:659) [wildfly-elytron-security-manager-1.13.1.Final.jar:1.13.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:213) [wildfly-jpa-21.0.0.Final.jar:21.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_221]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: com.berwick.dal] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1327) [hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1253) [hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:170) [wildfly-jpa-21.0.0.Final.jar:21.0.0.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [createDate] in table [audit.Address_AUD]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:136) [hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42) [hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89) [hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191) [hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) [hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) [hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1250) [hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    ... 12 more

18:58:48,277 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "bds-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"bds-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#com.berwick.dal\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: com.berwick.dal] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: com.berwick.dal] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [createDate] in table [audit.Address_AUD]"}}
18:58:48,280 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "bds-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"bds-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#com.berwick.dal\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: com.berwick.dal] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: com.berwick.dal] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [createDate] in table [audit.Address_AUD]"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply I need to add name to column matched field name in my case its `name="create_date"`

```
@Embeddable
public class TemporalEntity {

    @Column(name="create_date",updatable = false)
    private DateTime createDate;
```